# Reactjs var not defined inside a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a strange problem, I modified a working function from this:

```
    const reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };    

    const cfg = { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': this.store.user.token } };
        axios.post(endpoint.users+'/profilesetdata', reqBody, cfg)
            .then((result) => {
                //...
            })
            .catch((err) => {
               //...
            })
```

to this:

```
    // the condition is the difference
    if ( type == 'bio' ){
        const reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };    
    }else{
        const reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };
    }

    const cfg = { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': this.store.user.token } };
        axios.post(endpoint.users+'/profilesetdata', reqBody, cfg)
            .then((result) => {
                //...
            })
            .catch((err) => {
               //...
            })
```

Now happen a strange thing, in the first version the code working properly, in the second, the condition in reqBody cause this error:

> 'reqBody' is not defined  no-undef

Now, it's possible that the axios code is executed before the condition? Ok that the js is async but seems really strange this behaviour, someone can help me to understand why this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you defined the `reqBody` variable inside the if-else block. It would not be available outside that scope. You need to define it in a common-scope so that other logic within your function has access to it.

```
let reqBody;

if ( type == 'bio' ){
    reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };    
}else{
    reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };
}

const cfg = { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': this.store.user.token } };
    axios.post(endpoint.users+'/profilesetdata', reqBody, cfg)
        .then((result) => {
            //...
        })
        .catch((err) => {
           //...
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to a ternary, your const statement is inside an if block which means it wont be accessible outside

```
  const reqBody = type === bio?  { bio: this.state.infoContent } : { bio: this.state.infoContent };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the const reqBody is only in the if clause available where you define it. Declare it before the if as ,,let" and your problem should be solved

Answer (score 1):

What you are running into is a scoping issue. The `const` keyword scopes the `reqBody` to the block within the `if`.

To solve this problem you need to define the `reqBody` variable with `let` and outside of the block scope in the `if/else` like so:

```
let reqBody = {};
if ( type == 'bio' ){
        reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };    
    }else{
        reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `const` and `let` are designed to be scoped within `for` and `if` statements. You need to declare the variable first, then you can assign its value.

```
   let reqBody = null;

   if ( type == 'bio' ){
     reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };    
   } else{
     reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside of `if` `else` block you can't access to variable defined in `if` `else` block using `const` or `let`

do this instead:

```
let reqBody

if ( type == 'bio' ){
    reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };    
}else{
    reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };
}
```

otherwise use `var` in `if` `else` block:

```
if ( type == 'bio' ) {
    var reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };    
} else {
    var reqBody = { bio: this.state.infoContent };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define `reqBody` outside `if` statement. Your `const` is scoped to it. Try with `let` or `var` before `if`.

Comment: `let` has the same scope as `const`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare same variable name using `const` keyword in the same scope

**Illustration 1 (const) :**

```
const a = 1;

if(true){
    const  a = 2;
}
console.log(a);// logs 1
```

**Illustration 2(let) :**

```
let a = 1;

if(true){
    let a = 2;
}
console.log(a);// logs 2
```

Note that it works for let.

**Illustration 3 (redeclare with const):**

You can declare another variable name **a** with **const** keyword for instance in another function scope

```
    const a = 1;

    if(true){
        const a = 2;
    }

 function change(){
     const a = 3
     return a; 
}

console.log(a);// logs 1
change();
console.log(a);// logs 1 , outer scope remains unchanged 

console.log(change());//logs 3 i.e returned value of the function which was variable declared with const.
```

**Conclusion**:

I will advice you try to understand the differences between variable declaration with **const** , **let** and  **var** keywords.  This would prevent you from getting into trouble in the future. const and let keywords would not have been introduced if they act like var keyword :)